# NSTextField alignment when selected in NSTableView

Tags: macos, nstableview, nstextfield

I have a programmatically created NSTableView with n rows and 1 column.  The embedded text field is selectable, and not editable.  I am able to observe the mouseDown event in the text field, but as you can see in the image, the selected row is repositioned and word wrapped.  I suspect this may be related to the field editor, but my MacOS odyssey has proven me wrong innumerable times.

My question:  What do I need to do to maintain the layout of the selected row to be consistent with the other rows in the table?

Update: adding a textfield.cell.wraps = false to the tableview delegate eliminated the word wrap, but still have the issue with the selected text field indented.

[image]

Code snippets:
From the table delegate:

```
    func tableView (_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
    {
        let text = dataArray [row]
        var v = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier.init(rawValue: "TableColumn"), owner: self) as? MyTextFieldExt
        if v == nil
        {
            v = MyTextFieldExt ()
            v?.identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "TableColumn")
            v?.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
            v?.autoresizingMask = [.width]
            v?.setContentHuggingPriority(NSLayoutConstraint.Priority(rawValue: 251), for: .horizontal)
            v?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            v?.isEditable = false
            v?.isSelectable = true
            
            v?.cell?.wraps = false
        }
        
        v!.stringValue = text
        v!.font = NSFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 10, weight: .regular)
        v!.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3000, height: 0)

        return v!
    }
```

From the text field (custom) that traps the mouseDown:

```
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)
    {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)

        let cEditor = self.currentEditor() as? NSTextView
        let localPos = convert (event.locationInWindow, to: nil)

        let location = cEditor?.selectedRange().location

        if let r = cEditor?.selectedRange()
        {
            self.select(withFrame: self.frame, editor: cEditor!, delegate: self, start: r.location, length: r.length+10)
        }

    }
```

From the view controller that creates the scrollview, table view, and column:

```
    func setupTableView ()
    {
        let tableView = MyTableViewExt ()
        tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .none
        
        tableView.headerView = nil
        tableView.columnAutoresizingStyle = .lastColumnOnlyAutoresizingStyle
        tableView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        tableView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
        
        let column = NSTableColumn ()
        column.identifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "TableColumn")
        column.width = 426
        column.minWidth = 40
        column.maxWidth = 1000
        column.resizingMask = [.autoresizingMask, .userResizingMask] // verify in debugger
        
        tableView.addTableColumn(column)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        let scrollView = NSScrollView (frame: self.view.bounds)
        scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = [.height, .width]
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false        
        scrollView.hasHorizontalScroller = true
        scrollView.hasVerticalScroller = true
        
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint (item: self.view, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint (item: scrollView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint (item: self.view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint (item: scrollView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20))
        
        scrollView.documentView = tableView
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your code including layout constraints?

Comment: @Ron, I added the code that may be relevant to the issue.

Comment: What is the override of `mouseDown` supposed to do? `self.frame` is not "The bounding rectangle of the control’s cell.". Have you tried `cEditor?.setSelectedRange( … )`?

Comment: @Willeke The current mouseDown is just to demonstrate that I can trap the event and obtain the current caret position. With that I'll add additional logic to refine the selection based on the data itself, and when it's all done, move to implement a drag and drop feature. In the meantime, just to focus on the table/text field behavior, I've limited the code just to manipulating movement within the row/text field. I removed self.select (withFrame:...) section, I'll be damned, the indent behavior went away. Geez Louise.

Comment: You beat me to it. I was going to suggest commenting out that statement to see what happens. Not clear to me why you needed it anyway. So does this let you move forward with your project?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a single column? It appears you have several fields within a row, why not define several columns?

Comment: @Willeke Using the cEditor?.setSelectedRange solved my problem, and the text.cell?.wraps = false I added wasn't needed.  Thank you for your help. I appreciate that.

Comment: @Ron Each row contains a line from a text file, and has fields of varying dimensions and aren't expected to be aligned on offset and length. I thought the easiest approach is to just have a one column table and then select the specific field within the row that is of interest to the user, and then perform additional operations on the selected field. Replacing the  mouseDown self.select(...) with current editor setSelectedRange(...) solved my problem and I can move on.  That piece of  code was a just a clarification of another point I was testing, only to see it cause such an unexpected issue.

Comment: And for posterity and accuracy, the textfield.cell?.wraps in the tableview delegate was required.  My earlier comment on that was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

So my problem was resolved by modifying the code in the text field mouseDown logic.  The corrected code looks like this, with a change in setting the selected range:

```
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent)
    {
        super.mouseDown(with: event)

        let cEditor = self.currentEditor() as? NSTextView
        let localPos = convert (event.locationInWindow, to: nil)
        let insertionPoint = cEditor?.characterIndexForInsertion(at: localPos)
        let location = cEditor?.selectedRange().location

        if let r = cEditor?.selectedRange()
        {            
//          self.select(withFrame: self.frame, editor: cEditor!, delegate: self, start: r.location, length: r.length+10) <-- Source of problem
            cEditor?.setSelectedRange(NSMakeRange(r.location, r.length+10)) <-- Solution to problem
        }
    }
```

And just to be clear, the statement of not requiring the textfield.cell?.wraps = false I made in a comment is incorrect.  That line is needed in my table view delegate to avoid the word wrap.